# Get XML tag by variable

Tags: xml, vb.net

I've got the following code in VB 2012, which returns a correct XML:

```
Dim xml = XDocument.Load("http://myURL.com/api/request")
```

I know I can use the values form the XML this way:

```
Debug.WriteLine(xml.<response>.<label1>.<regel1>.<text>.Value)
```

But the problem is, that `label1` can also be `label2`, `label3` etc. How can i create something like this:

```
For iLabel as Integer = 1 To myArray.Length
    Debug.WriteLine(xml.<response>.<label + iLabel>.<regel1>.<text>.Value)
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`.Elements(XName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method, for example :

```
For iLabel as Integer = 1 To myArray.Length
    Debug.WriteLine(xml.<response>.Elements("label" & iLabel).<regel1>.<text>.Value)
Next
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. ty! According to the intellisense, `Elements` required an index. Tried it and was not working, didn't know I could also use a string (or var)